# How to access argparse parse_args from another function

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
args = {}

def do_something():
    print 'from do_something ', args

def my_parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A demo script')
    parser.add_argument('arg1', help='an arg')
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    print 'from my_parse_args ', args

if __name__=="__main__":
    my_parse_args()
    do_something()
```

I'm trying to access args from do_something() function. But, I get the following:

```
python demo.py example
from my_parse_args  {'arg1': 'example'}
from do_something  {}
```

Why is the args dictionary not getting set in my_parse_args() function?

Comment: I think you're looking for `global args` at the top of both functions. What's happening in `args = vars(parser.parse_args())` is you assigning something to a function-local variable `args`, not the one you declared outside of the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd *return* the parsing results from your function, so you can pass it to something else:

```
def do_something(args):
    print 'from do_something ', args

def my_parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A demo script')
    parser.add_argument('arg1', help='an arg')
    return vars(parser.parse_args())

if __name__=="__main__":
    args = my_parse_args()
    do_something(args)
```

Generally, you'd pick out the argument that `do_something()` needed and passed that in; that way the `do_something()` function can also be used by other code:

```
def do_something(foo):
    print 'from do_something', foo
```

and

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    args = my_parse_args()
    do_something(args['arg1'])
```

Here `do_something()` is driven by the command-line argument `arg1` value, but `do_something()` itself doesn't have to know how that value was obtained. You could also have loaded it from a configuration file or a database or from direct user input with a prompt after the program has started.